# CSS: Fixed layout but borders/background images across screen width

Tags: html, css

Perhaps I'm the last developer to ask this but I don't get it: 
I'm considering using a fixed width layout such as this one:
http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs02.php
Based on the screen size the left and right columns resize dynamically while the middle grid stays fixed. Great!
Now what I don't understand is that there are ton of websites out that use this approach but they also have page sections which have borders and background images that fill the complete screen width.

An example:
http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs02.php
The top strip, tab menu and footer sections have lines that extend out over the full screen width.

How do they do this?

Comment: You could use browser's developer tools to find it out yourself. There is a [good tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/chrome-dev-tools-markup-and-style/) on this.

Answer (score 0):

Pavlo, thanks for the tip!

So it turns out that there are container divs which are width 100 and float left which can contain design elements across the whole page width. Then the fixed grid divs are embedded into the container divs.

:)